# POST an array of custom objects to a Struts 2 action

Tags: java, arrays, post, struts2, forms

How do I POST an array of custom objects to a Struts 2 action in Java?

For example if I have the following Java object:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }   
}
```

And the following Action:

```
public class SavePersons extends ActionSupport {

    private List<Person> persons;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
            // Do something
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

}
```

I'd like to do something like this in an HTML form:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="http://postHere">
    <input type="text" name="persons[0].name" value="Name1"/>
    <input type="text" name="persons[0].lastName" value="LastName1"/>
    <input type="text" name="persons[1].name" value="Name2"/>
    <input type="text" name="persons[1].lastName" value="LastName2"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any tips?

Comment: **Quaternion** have answer your question. And your question is related to **[Tabular inputs](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/tabular-inputs.html)** of Struts2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have looks good. It does not make a difference to struts2 if you post or get as far as setting values.

Using the same SavePersons class, except that I added a `public List<Person> getPersons()` method. This is required to make the solution work.

And using essentially the same form, except I prefer to write my forms using s2 tags where it makes sense (what puts some people off the form tags is the default s2 theme, you can globally set the theme to simple, the label attribute will not work but the UI tags will work just like you'd expect similar html elements to behave):

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Person Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Person Form</h1>
        <s:form action="person-test" method="post">
            <s:textfield name="persons[0].name" label="fName 1"/>
            <s:textfield name="persons[0].lastName"  label="lName 1"/>
            <s:textfield name="persons[1].name" label="fName 2"/>
            <s:textfield name="persons[1].lastName" label="lName 2"/>
            <s:submit/>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that method="post" is not needed, it is the default.

Here is the page used to display the form data.

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>List of People</h1>
        <s:iterator value="persons">
            <s:property value="name"/> <s:property value="lastName"/><br/>
        </s:iterator>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem in my case is that if I don't declare a getter "getPersons" (because I don't want to read the list later), it doesn't work and the persons List is never populated on POST.

Comment: Can you use the iterator to create the form?

Comment: @Quaternion: @Mark has right regarding the fact that the `getPersons` getter is mandatory in order your solution to work. In fact the setter won't set the persons, the getter will be used to get the persons list and then all its elements will begin to be filled. Actually, I spent more than 4 hours yesterday (the last one with 4 of my colleagues) trying to figure out why it didn't work, your answer "getPersons is only to read..." was misleading us. Finally adding this getter has solved the problem.

Comment: @ahmehri I don't know what I was thinking, getters _are_ needed when setting collections. I'll delete my earlier comment in case it misleads someone.