# DYNAMIC FORM: how to pass a data as multi-dimensional array (Struts 2)

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, struts2, dynamic-forms

Is this what they call the `DYNAMIC FORMs`? 
HTML

```
<div id="myForm">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="question1" placeholder="Question 1"/>
    <input type="text" name="item1" placeholder="Item 1"/>

    <a href="#" onclick="addItem();">Add more items</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="addQuestion();">Add new question</a>
  </form>
</div>

<script> 
   function addQuestion() {
      // codes to add more input type=text like:
      $('#myForm').append('<input type="text" name="item2"/>');
   }
   function addItem() {
      // codes to add more input type=text like:
      $('#myForm').append('<input type="text" name="item2"/>');
   }
</script>
```

As a student, it is really complicated for me to think about these stuffs. 
My problem is that, I do not have any idea on how to pass multiple items or data on a form. And even what to put on a `name` attribute of an `<input>`. Also, if the user add more items! How could I pass these unexpected number of data.

Example also when the user wants to add more items or options.

Or should I implement these logic:

```
<form>...</form>
<a href="#" onclick="addForm();">Add a question</a>
<script>//codes to add new form</script>
```

And what I'm gonna do is just know how to pass multiple form. But if I do that, will the `Struts2` (`request.getParameter()` in mvc) to identify the data passed?

Please help,, this is just so complicated from a student like me.

EDITED:
The data to be pass is like a multi-dimensional array. For example:

```
[question1, [item1, item2, item3]],
[question2, [item1, item2, item3, item4]]
[question3, [item1, item2]]
```

In other words, in the form, the user can add more question, and in each question the user can add more items.

The main function is that the user can create `multiple-choice` quiz. So in each questions, there would be any number of item. `Where item = options or choices`.

Comment: for question nd item ll have the same index in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map request variables to a list of beans in struts2. Assuming you have the Parameters interceptor defined or are using the defaultStack.

1) Define a bean that contains

```
String question;
List<String> items;
```

2) Expose this bean as a list in your action class

```
List<MyBean> questions;
```

3) In your jsp send the request parameters like this.

```
<input type="text" name="questions[0].question" placeholder="Question 1"/>
<input type="text" name="questions[0].items[0]" placeholder="Item 1"/>
<input type="text" name="questions[0].items[1]" placeholder="Item 2"/>
<script> 
   var qcounter = 1;
   var icounter = 2;
   function addQuestion() {
      // codes to add more input type=text like:
      $('#myForm').append('<input type="text" name="questions[' + qcounter + '].question" placeholder="Question ' + (++qcounter) + '"/>');

      icounter = 0;

   }
   function addItem() {
      // codes to add more input type=text like:
      $('#myForm').append('<input type="text" name="questions[' + (qcounter - 1) + '].items[' + icounter + ']" placeholder="Item ' + (++icounter) + '"/>');
   }
</script>
```

You will have to consider what do when clicking the Add question button, in my example I am assuming that you want to reset the item count for the new question.

Here is a similar question about tabular form inputs in struts2. 
[POST an array of custom objects to a Struts 2 action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313790/post-an-array-of-custom-objects-to-a-struts-2-action)
Hope this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some thing for this, the sample code below.. in struts 2.x

**addRow.jsp**

```
<div id="myForm">
  <form method="post" action='submitForm.action'>
    <input type="text" name="questions" placeholder="Question 1"/>
    <input type="text" name="items" placeholder="Item 1"/>

    <a href="#" onclick="addItem();">Add more items</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="addQuestion();">Add new question</a>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
 </form>
</div>

<script> 
   function addQuestion() {
      // codes to add more input type=text like:
      $('#myForm').append('<input type="text" name="questions"/>');
   }
   function addItem() {
      // codes to add more input type=text like:
      $('#myForm').append('<input type="text" name="items"/>');
   }
</script>
```

**AddRowAction.java**

```
package action;    
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
    /**
     *
     * @author Prabhakar
     */
    public class AddRowAction extends ActionSupport{

    private String[] items;
    private String[] questions;

       public String[] getItems() {
            return items;
        }

        public void setItems(String[] items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public String[] getQuestion() {
            return question;
        }

        public void setQuestion(String[] question) {
            this.question = question;
        }


    public String getFormData()
    {

    for(String question : questions)

    System.out.println("The question in the index "+i+" is "+question)

    }
    for(String item : items)

    System.out.println("The Item in the index "+i+" is "+item)

    }
    return SUCCESS;
    }
```

**struts.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<!-- Author: Prabhakar -->
 <struts>

<package name="action.AddRowAction" extends="struts-default">

<action name="submitForm" class="action.AddRowAction"
        method="getFormData" >
    <result name="success">/addRow.jsp</result>
    </action>  
  </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: How do I know where a specific item belong, in which question?

Comment: @FireStatic for question nd item ll have the same index in the array.

Comment: i meant, each question can have many items. I'm sorry, i haven't cleared my posted question. But what i'm asking is that the user can add a question, and in each question, the user can add items. So it's like a multi-dimensional array. `[questions, [item1, item2, item3]] , [question2, [item1,item2,item3,item4,item5]]`